# Firebase database pagination for data which is depending on the timestamp

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I am applying the query to firebase node. I want pagination for data which is depending on the timestamp.

```
Node structure is as follows: 
     communityObjects -> 
          communityUsers -> 
                -KuPMcj9tSjJZx7Vkd-Y (Auto generated)-> 
                     users -> 
                       userId->(Custom) 
                        - field 1 
                        - field 2 
                        - timestamp 
                          ... 

    I make query like this-
```

FifrebaseRef = communityObjects -> communityUsers -> -KuPMcj9tSjJZx7Vkd-Y -> users

```
    FifrebaseRef.orderByChild("timestamp").endAt(CurrentTime).limitToLast(5).
```

It retrieves data but not ordering in a sorted manner. 
so next time I could not find with the latest timestamp.

Thanks:)

Comment: Your current code doesn't read anything from the database yet. If you're having problems, can you share the minimal listener that reproduces the problem? E.g. something that logs out the data in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can not send my project data with you. It retrieves data but not sorted according to timestamp field. Maybe it is a custom push key issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this While declaring variables we should match with firebase nodes. The variables name is case sensitive.